# how to group the data by a field into subarray in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below. I want to group this array by day field.

```
input_array = [{
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "monday",
  "time": "morning",
  "task": "studying"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "monday",
  "time": "evening",
  "task": "playing"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "monday",
  "time": "night",
  "task": "sleeping"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "sunday",
  "time": "morning",
  "task": "playing"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "sunday",
  "time": "evening",
  "task": "playing"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "sunday",
  "time": "night",
  "task": "sleeping"
}]
```

I want the result will be like the below array.

```
result_array = [{
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "monday",
  "schedule": [
    { "time": "morning", "task": "studying" },
    { "time": "evening", "task": "playing"  },
    { "time": "evening", "task": "sleeping" }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "sunday",
  "schedule": [
    { "time": "morning", "task": "playing"  },
    { "time": "evening", "task": "playing"  },
    { "time": "night",   "task": "sleeping" }
  ]
}]
```

What I mean is I want to group by day and then I have to make sub array schedule having elements of time and task. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get your required result from sample data by `foreach` and `map` functions :

```
const input_array = [{ "name":"alagu", "day":"monday", "time":"morning", "task":"studying" }, 
               { "name":"alagu", "day":"monday", "time":"evening", "task":"playing" },
               { "name":"alagu", "day":"monday", "time":"night", "task":"sleeping" },
               { "name":"alagu", "day":"sunday", "time":"morning", "task":"playing" },
               { "name":"alagu", "day":"sunday", "time":"evening", "task":"playing" }, 
               { "name":"alagu", "day":"sunday", "time":"night", "task":"sleeping" }]

const result = {};

inputArray.forEach(item => {
    const { name, day, time, task } = item;
    if (!result[day]) {
        result[day] = { name, day, schedule: [] };
    }
    result[day].schedule.push({ time, task });
});

const resultArray = Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key]);

console.log(resultArray);
```

**Result :**

```
[
   {
      "name":"alagu",
      "day":"monday",
      "schedule":[
         {
            "time":"morning",
            "task":"studying"
         },
         {
            "time":"evening",
            "task":"playing"
         },
         {
            "time":"night",
            "task":"sleeping"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"alagu",
      "day":"sunday",
      "schedule":[
         {
            "time":"morning",
            "task":"playing"
         },
         {
            "time":"evening",
            "task":"playing"
         },
         {
            "time":"night",
            "task":"sleeping"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: how to group the data by a field into subarray in *JavaScript*

Comment: code edited in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function like this:

```js
const input_array = [{
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "monday",
  "time": "morning",
  "task": "studying"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "monday",
  "time": "evening",
  "task": "playing"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "monday",
  "time": "night",
  "task": "sleeping"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "sunday",
  "time": "morning",
  "task": "playing"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "sunday",
  "time": "evening",
  "task": "playing"
}, {
  "name": "alagu",
  "day": "sunday",
  "time": "night",
  "task": "sleeping"
}]

const result_array = Object.entries(input_array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [curr.day]: curr.day in acc ? [...acc[curr.day], curr] : [curr]
  }
}, {})).map(([key, value]) => ({
  name: value[0].name,
  day: key,
  schedule: value.map(val => ({
    time: val.time,
    task: val.task
  }))
}))

console.log(result_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{"name":"alagu","day":"monday","time":"morning","task":"studying"},{"name":"alagu","day":"monday","time":"evening","task":"playing"},{"name":"alagu","day":"monday","time":"night","task":"sleeping"},{"name":"alagu","day":"sunday","time":"morning","task":"playing"},{"name":"alagu","day":"sunday","time":"evening","task":"playing"},{"name":"alagu","day":"sunday","time":"night","task":"sleeping"}]

let t, r = [...new Set(data.map(i=>i.day))]
  .map(day=>(t=data.filter(i=>i.day===day),
    {name: t[0].name, day, schedule: t.map(({name, day, ...o})=>o)}))

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally introduce a general purpose `groupBy()` helper, that allows you to group a collection based on a key.

```
function groupBy(iterable, fn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = fn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}
```

With this helper defined we group the data using:

```
const groups = groupBy(input_array, item => JSON.stringify([item.name, item.day]));
```

The reason I use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is because two arrays (objects) are only only equal to each other if they reference the same array. Therefore `[item.name, item.day]` will never match an existing key, since we just created the array instance. If we serialize the array (using JSON) we can compare 2 strings instead. Which are equal if they contain the same content.

```
// normal array comparison
["alagu", "monday"] === ["alagu", "monday"] //=> false

// serialized (using JSON) array comparison
'["alagu","monday"]' === '["alagu","monday"]' //=> true
```

After we've grouped the data, the `groups` structure looks like this:

```
// using object notation to display Map instance contents
Map{
  '["alagu","monday"]': [
    { name: "alagu", day: "monday", time: "morning", task: "studying" },
    { name: "alagu", day: "monday", time: "evening", task: "playing"  },
    { name: "alagu", day: "monday", time: "night"  , task: "sleeping" },
  ],
  '["alagu","sunday"]': [
    { name: "alagu", day: "sunday", time: "morning", task: "playing"  },
    { name: "alagu", day: "sunday", time: "evening", task: "playing"  },
    { name: "alagu", day: "sunday", time: "night"  , task: "sleeping" },
  ],
}
```

We can then convert this into an array using [`Array.from(groups)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the key/value pairs to transform them into the desired output.

```
const result_array = Array.from(groups).map(([json, items]) => {
  const [name, day] = JSON.parse(json);
  const schedule = items.map(({ time, task }) => ({ time, task }));
  return { name, day, schedule };
});
```

```js
const input_array = [
  { name: "alagu", day: "monday", time: "morning", task: "studying" },
  { name: "alagu", day: "monday", time: "evening", task: "playing"  },
  { name: "alagu", day: "monday", time: "night"  , task: "sleeping" },
  { name: "alagu", day: "sunday", time: "morning", task: "playing"  },
  { name: "alagu", day: "sunday", time: "evening", task: "playing"  },
  { name: "alagu", day: "sunday", time: "night"  , task: "sleeping" },
];

const groups = groupBy(input_array, item => JSON.stringify([item.name, item.day]));

const result_array = Array.from(groups).map(([json, items]) => {
  const [name, day] = JSON.parse(json);
  const schedule = items.map(({ time, task }) => ({ time, task }));
  return { name, day, schedule };
});

console.log(result_array);

// groupBy() helper
function groupBy(iterable, fn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = fn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}
```

In the above code we turn the serialized key back into a JavaScript structure using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), this allows us to grab the `name` and `day` of the current group.

We then need to transform `items`—an array of objects that still contain all the properties—into an array of objects that only have the `time` and `task` property.

`.map(({ time, task }) => ({ time, task }))` does exactly that. It is a combination of [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and the [property definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions).